# SQL Server / SSIS Updates are too Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a sql server 2008 table with over 200k users, each user has a unique userid but there are duplicated email addresses.

e.g.

```
email               userid
me@hotmail.com      12345
me@hotmail.com      678910
me@hotmail.com      111213
```

The userids span across various tables on various sql servers (2008,2005,2000). We want to merge users - so we end up with one email address and a chosen userid (I already have a procedure to select the correct userid).

The problem is, it is taking 4 mins in SSIS to update each user (using sprocs to scan through tables looking for old userids and updating to the one we want to keep). Working this out it means the whole process will take 615 days!!!

Is there any other way of doing this?

Would appreciate any help or advice you can offer!
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using SSIS to run stored procedures?

Comment: We're going to need more detail about what your code you are actually running to do the clean up that is taking 4 minutes per user.

Comment: We selected SSIS because we needed to run the process on multiple servers at the same time. I am able to open connections to all of them concurrently. Generally in the past calling sprocs from SSIS has not been slow. This is whole different task I have been set though!

Comment: This is a snippet:IF EXISTS(SELECT UserID FROM [DB].dbo.table WHERE UserID = old) 
 BEGIN 
 UPDATE [DB].dbo.table
 SET userID= new
 WHERE UserID= old
 END
 ELSE INSERT INTO MergeError (UserID, Error) VALUES (old,'Does not exist in [DB].dbo.table')

Comment: Start from your execution plans and work up.  Are you missing indexes?

Comment: Mixing SSIS and stored procedures I"m guessing you are doing this in a For Each Loop when you don't have to.... When you perform this operation is all of the data required on the same SQL Server or do you have some kind of master data in a central server. You need to explain your process in more detail in order for us to help, i.e. where are the datasets, how is your package set up, what is the source code to your SP?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the latest ID to be the winner:

```
update
   TableContainingUserIDs
set
userid = IDTOKeep
from
TableContainingUserIDs
inner join (
    select max(userid) over (partition by email) as IDToKeep, userid as OldUserID
    from
    tbl
) KeeperSet
on KeeperSet.userid = TableContainingUserIDs.userID
```

If you have some other logic for picking winner IDs, either create a query or a temporary table that houses the data in the format

IDToKeep OldUserID

and then replace the KeeperSet alias in that query with your query/table.

Then just rinse and repeat for each secondary table with userids.

If you are using SSIS, instead of a stored procedure, why not use a staging table and then update in one batch?

1. Create a Data Flow Task. Push your IDToKeep OldUserID query/table to your destination server as a staged table.
2. Create an Execute SQL Task and run the above query against the destination server, using the staged table as the KeeperSet.
3. Drop the KeeperSet staged table when you're done.

The stored procedure isn't slow, the problem is running an OLEDB Command at the end of a Data Flow Task on a row-by-row basis completely defeats the purpose of databases and set theory. Stage your data to the same database, run one set-based query, and you're done.

Comment: Other than my experience tells me that the most recent id is almost always the worst one to keep (it is usually the one with the fewest related records thus requiring much more extensive updates than if you keep the older one), this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step is to create a temporary table of reference data for example:

```
fromId toId
-------------
1234   34567
1235   34567
1236   789
```

etc...

Then load this data into each database instance.

Then use a cursor to select each record in turn and run an update statement based on the cursor for each table needing updating.

This process is then all running within SQL and within the same machine.  It can also be run in parallel across servers and instances.